# How to call nose in bamboo

Tags: nose, bamboo

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Bamboo in my context.  I have functional tests that live in a separate repo from the actual product that is being built.  We are trying to use Bamboo to checkout and build code, run unit/integration tests and if all passes run functional tests.  The requirement here is that the functional tests run on a remote client that talk to the server that checked out/built code and ran all unit/integration tests.  I installed a remote agent of this server to run functional tests from set up a command capability in the remote agent.  Problem is I need to start in a different working directory to call my tests. Also once tests are called I need Bamboo to consume those results.  I see its easiest if they are xunit output so i can pass the --with-xunit to nose but do i jsut move the results to the bamboo working directory on the server and bamboo will automatically parse those?

Answer (score 6):

You need to also add a JUnit Parser task in your plan that will read the nose xunit xml output and make sense of it.

So the steps would be something like:

1. Pull from repo
2. Run your nosetest --with-xunit command
3. Create a JUnit parser task to look for the nose output xml. Default is nosetests.xml I think

Once Bamboo reaches step 3 it will know if tests passed or failed and it will terminate the build.

Hope that helps.

G

Comment: This works great, but doesn't show error'd tests.  At least not in our version of bamboo.